# What to do with a missing common pin for a DC DC module on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, isolation, pcb-assembly

I made a big mistake while designing a board and it was printed out with 4 pins for the MDD02L-05 instead of 5.

What can I do with the common pin on the isolated converter?

I think folding the pin is one of the options, but can I still save the board and somehow connect it to isolated ground?

I don't have any isolated grounds except on the output of the isolation (J5 on picture.)

[The documentation.](https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=821#1)

The picture shows the part of the PCB that contains the MDD02L-05 and its output and test-points.

[image: part of the PCB board contains the MDD02L-05 and its output and test-points]

Comment: Glue it on its back and solder the pins with wires to appropriate pads. Could be a problem for heat dissipation though

Comment: I would drill a hole to allow the common pin to pass through the board, then solder a wire from that pin to wherever it should connect.

Comment: If drilling a hole for the pin, just make sure there are no traces or planes under that area.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the common pin 6 needs not just a wire, but a fairly low impedance one depending on how much imbalance current there is between Vout+ and Vout-. If your common ground is nearby this shouldn't be a problem.

So a couple of ways to deal with this.

Option 1: Carefully drill the PCB with hole for the missing pin, making sure your inner layers aren't shorted out to each other. Put a sleeve on the pin using a small piece of Kapton tape so that it doesn't touch the inner layers. Mount the part, then apply your jumper (it should be very short - to a plane if possible.) This gives the visually cleanest result and best performance, and most closely resembles a board with updated artwork to fix the problem.

Option 2: Bend the pin on the device and attach the jumper lead. Apply a piece of Kapton to the board where your pin is supposed to be (this is to insulate the board from the bent pin.) Mount the part and connect the jumper. Not as clean looking, and the common wire might add impedance.

Not-an-option: 'dead-bug' rework (part mounted on its side, with wires attaching the leads.) This adds too much impedance to the lines which affects the power supply performance.

Bear in mind that a rework like this would only be for prototype debug. Expect to spin the board later to clean it up. Any EMI / ESD work would have to be redone on fixed artwork, since a critical signal (ground) is being altered.

Answer (score 2):

Option 3: Pigtail out all wires off the board with high gauge (like AWG22 or AWG18, whatever fits in the through hole) so everything is easily accessible. *maybe an inch or half inch of wire.
If your ground is on the 1 or 2 layer, you could just scrape off the soldermask to get to it or solder to another component ground.

Keep in mind this will add a small amount of resistance and inductance from the wires that may change the design, but should get you prototyping.

Another thing: most of those DC to DC converters have standard pins so it's good to put in the full set on all converters in your library even if the pins are unused for exactly this reason.